# How can I see installation notes of an already installed software with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

After the installation of a software with homebrew some formula give installation notes like:

```
==> Upgrading git
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-1.8.5.4.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Pouring git-1.8.5.4.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
...
```

How can I review these notes for an already installed formula? I cannot remember how to start and stop mysql and I know it was noted after the homebrew installation.

Answer (score 8):

Use `brew info` to view the Caveats once again:

```
$ brew info git

git: stable 1.9.1 (bottled), HEAD
...
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
...
```